# R: Reduce number of plots in quantile regression results

Tags: r, plot, quantile, eps, quantile-regression

By using the following code I am able to plot the results of my quantile regression model:

```
quant_reg_all <- rq(y_quant ~ X_quant, tau = seq(0.05, 0.95, by = 0.05), data=df_lasso)
quant_plot <- summary(quant_reg_all, se = "boot")
plot(quant_plot)
```

However, as there are many variables the plots are unreadable as shown in the image below:
[image]

Including the label, I have 18 variables.

How could I plot a few of these images at the time so they are readable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

depending on the number of graphs you cant, you could do:

```
quant_reg_all <- rq(y_quant ~ X_quant, tau = seq(0.05, 0.95, by = 0.05), data=df_lasso)
quant_plot <- summary(quant_reg_all, se = "boot")
plot(quant_plot, 1:3)# plot the first 3
plot(quant_plot, c(3, 6, 9, 10))# plot the 3rd, 6th, 9th and 10th plots
```